# Upload temporary file and read using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, file-upload, apache-poi, fileinputstream

Now I get to read an xls file using Apache POI to put these information in a database. But it is server / server and I have to do this in client / server.

I use JSP 2.0

**index.xhtml**

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

I would like to recover xls file that the client will uploadet to implement it directly into the code just below instead of "/home/myfile.xls"

```
public void updateDB() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/myfile.xls"));
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

For several days I'm stuck on this point and I can not forward!

Comment: You could use a ```$param[var]``` as shown here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsp20-138721.html     The implicit objects are for this purpose.

Comment: you have an issue in reading the uploaded file or uploading the file ?

Comment: In the upload file, I managed to download the file to the customer but the party upload to replace "/home/myfile.xls" by the file upload the client is a real headache for me. I try with Servlet but I do not really understand.